# How to get the current thymeleaf version from spring boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot 2.1.0.RELEASE project. How can I see the thymeleaf version it uses?

Comment: are you asking `Spring Boot Thymeleaf Starter` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Maven, you can use [`list`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html) goal of [maven dependency plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/):

```
$ mvn dependency:list -DincludeArtifactIds=thymeleaf
```

Or with Maven Wrapper:

```
$ ./mvnw dependency:list -DincludeArtifactIds=thymeleaf
```

Example output for maven:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:list (default-cli) @ site ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:3.0.9.RELEASE:compile
```

For **Gradle**:

```
$ gradle dependencyInsight --dependency org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf
```

With Wrapper:

```
$ ./gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf
```

Example output for Gradle:

```
org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:2.1.6.RELEASE (selected by rule)
\--- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:2.1.6.RELEASE
     \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:1.5.9.RELEASE
          \--- compile

org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:2.1.4.RELEASE -> 2.1.6.RELEASE
\--- nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:1.4.0
     \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:1.5.9.RELEASE
          \--- compile

org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:2.1.6.RELEASE (selected by rule)
\--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:1.5.9.RELEASE
     \--- compile
```

See also [Inspecting dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/inspecting_dependencies.html)

Comment: Ohhhh thanks :D `The following files have been resolved: org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:3.0.11.RELEASE:compile`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using IntelIJ, a nice and simple solution is to click on Maven Projects (on the right) and expand the dependencies.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to Spring Docs, you can easily do this with your application properties file.

> You can automatically expand properties from the Maven project using
>   resource filtering. If you use the spring-boot-starter-parent you can
>   then refer to your Maven ‘project properties’ via @..@ placeholders

**Maven pom.xml:**

```
<groupId>com.poo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gar</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Poo</name>
<description>Gar</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

**Spring application.properties:**

```
poo.app.version=@project.version@
```

2. Then a class annotated with @ControllerAdvice can be used to inject version as model attribute.

   ```
    @ControllerAdvice 
    public class ControllerAdvice {

   @Value("${poo.app.version}")
   private String applicationVersion;

   @ModelAttribute("applicationVersion")
   public String getApplicationVersion() {
       return applicationVersion;
   }}
   ```
3. Finally this model attribute can be accessed by Thymeleaf as any other. With a th:text tag, try to access the model attribute below so you can display what version of Thymeleaf your app is using:

   `${applicationVersion}`

Comment: Thanks, need only see thymeleaf version, the sintaxis of 2.x and 3.x are difference, need see is 2 or 3. pom.xml: `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>` have not the version.