# Thymeleaf won't recognize variable in HomeController and Java error in creating bean "homeController"

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've been debugging this web app for 2 hours now and I can't figure this out.

After placing the version variable in the application, removing the temp H2 DB and the data.sql file, then adding the driver to the pom.xml file to use the Postgres DB, it stopped working.

I attached all the necessary files but if you need something please comment.

In the `application.properties` I gave the variable `version` then used that in the `HomeController` (line 24) and the corresponding console error says, "could not resolve placeholder 'version'."

In the browser usually, there are error messages that I can dig through, but this time the browser on the localhost simply fails to load, `This site can’t be reached, localhost refused to connect.`

There are only two "Caused by" errors in the console logs below so I'm sure it is not that difficult to point out the bug.

After lots of research on StackOverflow, looking at other questions, and trial and error, I have run out of possible solutions to try that are applicable to my case. Would really appreciate it if someone would take a look at the attached code and let me know about any solutions. Any help is appreciated! Thank you very much in advance and I will check back.

Here's the file structure if that helps at all

[image: file structure part 1]

Here's the 2nd part:

[image: file structure part 2]

The `spring.datasource.username=postgres` is underlined in yellow in eclipse as well as the `version=3.0.0` at the bottom, when I hover over the yellow line it says, "unknown property" on both.

Here is my application.properties file and the screenshot:

[image: application.properties file screenshot]

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pma-database
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password321

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
version=3.0.0
```

Here's the HomeController.java you'll see the @Value("${version}") is here on line 24 or so and the model.addAttribute("versionNumber", ver) is on line 36.

```java
package com.project1.controllers;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.project1.dao.EmployeeRepository;
import com.project1.dao.ProjectRepository;
import com.project1.dto.ChartData;
import com.project1.dto.EmployeeProject;
import com.project1.entities.Project;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
        
    @Value("${version}")
    private String ver;

    @Autowired
    ProjectRepository proRepo; 
    
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository empRepo;
        
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String displayHome(Model model) throws JsonProcessingException {
        
        model.addAttribute("versionNumber", ver);
        
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        
        //we are querying the DB for projects
        List<Project> projects = proRepo.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("projectsList", projects);
        
        List<ChartData> projectData = proRepo.getProjectStatus();
        
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(projectData);
        //[ ["NOTSTARTED, 1], ["INPROGRESS", 2], ["COMPLETED", 1] ]
        
        model.addAttribute("projectStatusCnt", jsonString);
    
        //we are querying the DB for employees
        List<EmployeeProject> employeesProjectCnt = empRepo.employeeProjects();
        model.addAttribute("employeesListProjectsCnt", employeesProjectCnt);
        
        return "main/home";
    }
    
}
```

Here's the `home.html` file which has the `versionNumber` variable in the  tag,  which is related to the issue at hand.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<!-- this is the code for the header-->
<head th:replace="layouts::header"></head>
<!-- this is the code for the navbar-->
<nav th:replace="layouts::navbar"></nav>
<body>


<div class="container">

<h3>Main Dashboard</h3>
    <a th:text="${versionNumber}"></a>
    <hr>
    <h4> Current Projects </h4>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead class="thead-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <th> Project Name </th>
                                <th> Project Stage </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr th:each="aProject : ${projectsList}">
                                <td th:text="${aProject.name}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${aProject.stage}"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
        
        
        <div class="col-md-4">
                <canvas id="myPieChart" height="50" width="50"></canvas>
                <script>
                    var chartData = "[[${projectStatusCnt}]]"
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
            
    <div class="container">
        <h4> Current Employees </h4>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                        
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                            <thead class="thead-dark">
                                <tr>
                                    <th> First Name </th>
                                    <th> Last Name </th>
                                    <th> Project Count</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr th:each="aEmployeeProjectCnt : ${employeesListProjectsCnt}">
                                    <td th:text="${aEmployeeProjectCnt.firstName}"></td>
                                    <td th:text="${aEmployeeProjectCnt.lastName}"></td>
                                    <td th:text="${aEmployeeProjectCnt.projectCount}"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>  
            </div>
        </div>  
        

    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/myChart.js}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the `Employee` class which has the `GenerationStrategy`. I tried
both `GenerationTypes` listed but they give the same exact error in the console logs.

```java
@Id annotation
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="employee_seq")
```

Again the code snippet below was also tried but that gave me the same exact error as the code that I have attached below and these were recommendations from stackoverflow, but the application still won't work.

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="employee_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(allocationSize=1, name = "employee_generator")
```

Here's the `Employee` class

```java
package com.project1.entities;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

@Entity
public class Employee {
        
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="employee_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize=1, name = "employee_generator")
    private long employeeId;
    
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST},
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="project_employee",
                joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="employee_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="project_id")
    )
    

    private List<Project> projects;
    
    
    
    public Employee() {
        
    }
    
    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }
    
    
    public List<Project> getProjects() {
        return projects;
    }

    public void setProjects(List<Project> projects) {
        this.projects = projects;
    }
    public long getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }
    public void setEmployeeId(long employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Also the same thing with the `Project` class

```java
package com.project1.entities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

@Entity
public class Project {
        
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="project_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize=1, name = "project_generator")
    
    private long projectId;
    private String name;
    private String stage; // NOTSTARTED, COMPLETED, INPROGRESS
    private String description;
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST},
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="project_employee",
                joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="project_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="employee_id")
    )
    private List<Employee> employees;
        
    public Project() {
        
    }
    
    public Project(String name, String stage, String description) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.stage = stage;
        this.description = description;
    }
    
    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    public long getProjectId() {
        return projectId;
    }
    public void setProjectId(long projectId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getStage() {
        return stage;
    }
    public void setStage(String stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    
    //convenience method
    public void addEmployee(Employee emp) {
    if(employees == null) {
        employees = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    employees.add(emp);
}
    
    
}
```

Here's the error message:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
{spring.web.resources.chain.cache=false, spring.web.resources.cache.period=0}

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.0)

2020-12-06 19:57:50.893  INFO 8560 --- [  restartedMain] com.project1.PmaApplication              : Starting PmaApplication using Java 14.0.2 on DESKTOP-C26F0I7 with PID 8560 (C:\Users\kashi\git\PMA-Application\PMA-Application\target\classes started by kashi in C:\Users\kashi\git\PMA-Application\PMA-Application)
2020-12-06 19:57:50.897  INFO 8560 --- [  restartedMain] com.project1.PmaApplication              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-12-06 19:57:50.975  INFO 8560 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-12-06 19:57:50.975  INFO 8560 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-12-06 19:57:51.832  INFO 8560 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-12-06 19:57:51.902  INFO 8560 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 59 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-12-06 19:57:52.673  INFO 8560 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-12-06 19:57:52.682  INFO 8560 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-12-06 19:57:52.683  INFO 8560 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.39]
2020-12-06 19:57:52.779  INFO 8560 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-12-06 19:57:52.779  INFO 8560 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1803 ms
2020-12-06 19:57:52.843  INFO 8560 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-12-06 19:57:52.977  INFO 8560 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-12-06 19:57:53.025  INFO 8560 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:c7335b0f-bd3a-43dd-9628-9ea69397c416'
2020-12-06 19:57:53.116  INFO 8560 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-12-06 19:57:53.268  INFO 8560 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-12-06 19:57:53.381  INFO 8560 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-12-06 19:57:53.397  WARN 8560 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'version' in value "${version}"
2020-12-06 19:57:53.397  INFO 8560 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-12-06 19:57:53.460  INFO 8560 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.23.Final
2020-12-06 19:57:53.619  INFO 8560 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2020-12-06 19:57:53.752  INFO 8560 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2020-12-06 19:57:54.169  WARN 8560 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.project1.entities.Project]
2020-12-06 19:57:54.169  INFO 8560 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-12-06 19:57:54.389  WARN 8560 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor': org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-200]
2020-12-06 19:57:54.392  INFO 8560 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-12-06 19:57:54.400  INFO 8560 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-12-06 19:57:54.405  INFO 8560 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-12-06 19:57:54.439  INFO 8560 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-12-06 19:57:54.489 ERROR 8560 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'version' in value "${version}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:405) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1415) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:608) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at com.project1.PmaApplication.main(PmaApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'version' in value "${version}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:178) ~[spring-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124) ~[spring-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239) ~[spring-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[spring-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:931) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1308) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

The parent tag right underneath the model version in the `pom.xml` file is underlined in red and when I hover over it it shows this.

```
Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources failed: newPosition < 0: (-1 < 0) (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources:default-resources:process-resources)

org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources failed: newPosition < 0: (-1 < 0)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.lambda$8(MavenImpl.java:1379)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1378)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$1(MavenBuilder.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$0(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: newPosition < 0: (-1 < 0)
    at java.base/java.nio.Buffer.createPositionException(Buffer.java:334)
    at java.base/java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:309)
    at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.position(ByteBuffer.java:1309)
    at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.position(ByteBuffer.java:266)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1946)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile(DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.filterResources(DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute(ResourcesMojo.java:356)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    ... 30 more
```

Here's the pom.xml file and the  tag right underneath the model version

[image: pom.xml file screenshot]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.project1</groupId>
    <artifactId>PMA-Application</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>PMA-Application</name>
    <description>The PMA Web App</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I got it according to the solution presented in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53158550/how-to-get-the-current-thymeleaf-version-from-spring-boot-project

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem, hope I can still help somebody with this.

If you're using eclipse go to

File > Properties > Java Build Path > Source

and now under src/main/resources at "Excluded" it said for me "**", make sure to delete this entry so that it sais "(None)". Fixed it for me.

Answer (score -2):

add @PropertySource({"classpath:resource.properties"}) on your controller

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer to the question.

Comment: It is a Spring Boot application which loads `application.properties` already. Also `@PropertySOurce` should be placed, ideally, on an `@Configuration` class and not scattered throughout your whole codebase on arbitrary components.

Comment: Thank you for your solutions. I tried adding the @PropertySource({"classpath:resource.properties"}) to the controller, but that didn't work. I also tried the PropertySource on a @Configuration class but that also did not work. Still checking for other solutions, but I appreciate your help. Thank you all.